# Java JAR memory usage VS class file memory usage

Tags: java, profiling

I recently changed my large Java application to be delivered in JARs instead of individual class files.  I have 405 JARS which hold 5000 class files. My problem is that when I run my program(s) as JARs (classpath is a wildcard to get all JARs) Java will continually use more and more memory.  I have seen the memory go > 2GB and it seems like Java is not doing stop-the-world garbage collections to keep the memory lower.  If I run the exact same program against the exploded JARs (only class files), Java's memory usage stays much lower (< 256MB) and stays there.  This is happening in Oracle's Java 8 on Windows 7 (x64) and Windows Server (x64).  Why would packaging my application as JARs change the memory profile?  Also I have run the program for a long time as JARs with the memory maximum limited to 128MB with no problems so I don't have a memory leak.

With JAR files in classpath
[image: With JAR files in classpath]

With class files in classpath 
[image: With class files in classpath]

Edit: I accepted the answer from @K Erlandsson because I think it is the best explanation and this is just an ugly quirk of Java.  Thanks every one (and especially @K Erlandsson) for your help.

Comment: Is this heap usage or overall footprint? Is it running in a web container? Does it have a custom class loading mechanism?

Comment: I am looking at both heap/overall I think.  I have looked at the memory usage through jconsole and it keeps growing the heap.  I can look at it through Windows task manager also and the memory (private working set) just keeps growing.  I am not using a custom class loading mechanism.  This is a standalone java process (no tomcat, etc.) and is running from the command line.

Comment: If it's the heap that is growing, I'd probably take a snapshot of it when it's ballooned up (with `visualvm` for example) and analyse it.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but if I use jvisualvm.exe to force a GC (mark sweep) the heap memory usage will drop clearing almost all the heap memory.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose from the distance but if there's enough memory (and `-Xmx` is sufficiently high), full GCs will occur much less frequently. It could well be that opening all those JAR files multiple times leaves a lot of garbage behind and without the need to clean up the application just grows and grows. Eventually a full GC will occur and collect all of it. If this is the case, it's a good example where keeping the maximum heap low with `-Xmx` can be a good thing.

Comment: It's conceivable that a lot more temporary objects are created when accessing a jar file for classes.

Comment: I would also try packaging everything into one jar as an experiment. 400 jars isn't extraordinarily many but for 5000 class files it feels like a bit of an overkill.

Comment: I understand if the program uses a larger base amount of memory for JAR file processing, but it doesn't make sense to me that it would keep growing.  Neither class file or JAR file have contrained top memory (Xmx) and Java says the max amount of memory in both cases is 3GB.  I am doing another jvisualvm.exe trace so I can attach a picture.

Comment: I think I did try everything in one JAR and it was better but I don't remember now. I will try that again biziclop.. Good idea.

Comment: Are these jars just on the classpath, are you using `java -jar`, jnlp, or onejar?

Comment: I either run it like this for the jars: java -cp c:\temp\test\* com.test.Test or this for the class files: java -cp c:\temp\test com.test.Test

Comment: I wonder if you have a duplicate class (same package and name, but different class files in different jars). The classloader might be choosing a different one, and one has a memory leak, but the other doesn't.

Comment: If I limit the amount of memory to use -Xmx128m it runs fine so I feel good that there isn't a memory leak.

Comment: I don't like this... these shouldn't be a large difference in memory usage. I second the suggestion to make it all **one** jar file, list that explicitly in the command line, and see how that goes. I think your wildcard classpath may be picking up more files than you think.

Comment: Is this a problem?  The JVM will do garbage collection when it needs to, which is why this works fine when you limit the heap to 128MB.  But if you've got a big heap, and it's not all used up, then the fact that the JVM hasn't stopped what it's doing to do a big garbage collect is surely a good thing, not a bad thing, right?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on vacation.  Yes, it is a problem because my program *used* to use < 128MB of memory on my customer's servers (rightfully so) and now my processes will eat up GBs of RAM which a) *could* affect system performance and b) makes my customer think that there is a memory leak in my process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that how much memory that is totally used on the heap is not very interesting at all times, since much of the used memory can be garbage and will be cleared by the next GC.

It is how much heap that is used by *live* objects that you need to be concerned about. You write in a comment:

> I don't know if this matters, but if I use jvisualvm.exe to force a GC
>   (mark sweep) the heap memory usage will drop clearing almost all the
>   heap memory.

This matters. **A lot**. This means that when you see a higher heap usage when you use your jars, you see more *garbage*, not more memory consumed by live objects. The garbage is cleared when you do a GC and all is well.

Loading classes from jar files will consume more memory, temporarily, than loading them from class files. The jar files need to be opened, seeked, and read from. This requires more operations and more temporary data than simply opening a specific `.class` file and reading it.

Since most of the heap usage is cleared by a GC, this additional memory consumption is not something you need to be very concerned about.

You also write:

> Java will continually use more and more memory. I have seen the memory
>   go > 2GB and it seems like Java is not doing stop-the-world garbage
>   collections to keep the memory lower.

This is typical behavior. The GC only runs when the JVM thinks it is necessary. The JVM will tune this depending on memory behavior.

**Edit:** Now that we see your jConsole images we see a difference in *committed* heap memory (250 mb vs 680 mb). Committed heap is the actual size of the heap. This will vary (up to what you set with `-Xmx`) depending on what that JVM thinks will yield the best performance for your application. However, it will mostly increase, almost never decrease.

For the jar case the JVM has assigned a bigger heap to your application. Probably due to more memory being required during the initial class loading. The JVM then thought a bigger heap would be faster.

When you have a bigger heap, more committed memory, there is more memory to use before running a GC. That is why you see the difference in memory usage in the two case.

**Bottom line:** All the extra usage you see is garbage, not live objets, why you do not need to be concerned about this behavior unless you have an actual problem since the memory will be reclaimed on the next GC.

Comment: The weird thing is (and I will have jconsole.exe pictures soon) that the JAR classpath causes the memory to *keep* growing unlike the class files.  It does make sense to me that the JARs would initially cause more garbage but it doesn't make sense that it would cause the JAR files to eventually use a GB or RAM when the class classpath uses a very small fraction of that (< 128m).

Comment: @Adam but is not that only that you see different gc behavior in the two cases? The initial burst will tune the gc differently.

Comment: The class file garbage collection looks more like I expect ramping up, collecting back to start and then starting over.  The JARs just keep growing with smaller garbage collections having little effect.

Comment: @Adam it could be that the committed heap is larger when you use jars. The jvm increases the committed part as needed and might have increased that more in the jar case. But its hard to guess without more info such as gc logs or jstat -gc output

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the base amount of memory could definitely be different but I don't understand (as you can hopefully see in the pictures in my latest edit) why the memory for the JARs would *keep* growing way larger that the class file run.

Comment: From the pictures above I think you are generally correct that Java has created a bunch of garbage because of the JAR files.  However, I still have the problem that my customers think I have a memory leak in my application and I am also concerned that this unnecessary RAM eating could cause a performance problems in the future.  I know that if I was debugging a system performance problem and I see one process taking 2GB of RAM I would point my finger directly to it.  I think I might try calling System.gc() (ug!) to force Java to collect to see if that improves anything.

Comment: @Adam Why don't you just set -Xmx to 128 Mb? That seems to be enough from what you have written and then all these "problems" go away.

Comment: @K Erlandsson Yeah, I think you are correct and that is what I am going to have to do.  It just feels like Java shouldn't have such wildly different memory usage for the exact same underlying class files.  I think the G1GC might help this also.  Thanks for you help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common to load resources from the classpath. When a resource is originated from a jar file, the URL object will keep a reference to the jar file entry. This might be adding some memory consumption. It's possible to disable this caching by disabling default url caching.

The API for disabling default URL caching is quite awkward:

```
public static void disableUrlConnectionCaching() {
    // sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection leaves the JarFile instance open if URLConnection caching is enabled.
    try {
        URL url = new URL("jar:file://valid_jar_url_syntax.jar!/");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // ignore
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

Disable default URL caching in the startup of your application.

Tomcat already disables URL caching by default because it also causes file locking issues and prevents updating jar files in a running application.

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/5bbbcb1f8ca224efeb8e8308089817e30e4011aa/java/org/apache/catalina/core/JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java#L408-L423

Comment: This code looks like it would disable URL caching for JARs that are loaded in the future right?  Would this work if the JARs are on the classpath and (I assume) already cached?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. This only helps if your application uses ClassLoader/Class.getResource to load resources from the classpath.